# bind9named binary missing - not starting

Tags: debian, dns, bind

I have just compiles and installed BIND 9.9.1-P1 on Debian 6.0 as the version in the repositories is too old for Samba4, and am getting the said error. I have been looking for source for named, but cannot find any.

```
# ls ¦ grep named in /usr/sbin
named-checkconf
named-checkzone
named-compilezone
```

Comment: try `sudo su; which named`

Comment: Version in Debian stable is 9.8.4, so quite recent and I really wonder why Samba would need anything so specific as BIND version 9.9.

Answer (score 1):

If you install from source, the installation prefix very often (not entirely always) defaults to `/usr/local` rather than `/usr`. So assuming that you did go through the installation properly, you should be looking in /usr/local/bin.

That said, the canonical daemon name for BIND 9 is `named`, not `bind9named`.

You can try something like `find / -type f -name named -perm /111 -ls` (yes, there's supposed to be a slash there) to find out where the `named` executable is. The `-perm /111` will limit the results to files which have the executable bits set, and the `-type f` excludes anything that is not an ordinary file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a:

```
make install
```

to install the binaries?

You can also try:

```
locate named
```